# change app theme by user selection in react native by context api

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my app there is a theme selected by the user, I use context API and Asyncstorage to store the app's background color and when the user selects the new color it should affect the app using context API.

Still, when the app removes from the background activity and starts again it should not show the previously selected color, instead, it shows the default color. Please help ...

Answer (score 0):

Every time the application is opened, check whether there is data you keep in Asyncstorage in the theme provide. You can update the Context API.